# Problem with Rabbitmq cluster in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I successfully setup RabbitMQ cluster by helm usig this chart (https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/rabbitmq-ha) in k8s, but can't create connection with server in my exteranl .net core application. Receiving such exception:

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: "None of the specified endpoints were reachable
```

I have enabled ingress and have access to rmq managment console with hostname. I checked ports(5672, 15672) in docker containers, they are opened. What is wrong with this?

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.1", GitCommit:"4ed3216f3ec431b140b1d899130a69fc671678f4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-10-05T16:36:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.1", GitCommit:"4ed3216f3ec431b140b1d899130a69fc671678f4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-10-05T16:36:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `ingress`? That's just HTTP(S). You should have the broker exposed as a service, either as ClusterIP or LoadBalancer -- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types

Comment: @evilSnobu, yes, of course i exposed by service. If you will look in this chart, you will see that deployment create two services:
1)client-facing one, designed to be used for client connections to the RabbitMQ cluster with port forwarding or using a LoadBalancer   
I am truuing to use port-forwarding.
2)and service discovery - a headless service for connections between the RabbitMQ nodes.

Saying "ingress", i just mean that in values.yaml, i am set ingress enable to true.